# Numbers whose powers are almost integers

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, recreational-mathematics, exponentiation

Some real numbers $\alpha$ have the property that their powers get ever closer to being integers -- more precisely, that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \alpha^n-[\alpha^n] = 0 $$
where $[\cdot]$ is the round-to-nearest-integer function.

This is trivially the case when $\alpha$ is itself an integer as well as when $|\alpha|<1$. But there are also other numbers with this property, such as $\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ (the golden ratio), $2+\sqrt3$, or $\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}2$. (The trick for each of these is that $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ solves a second-order integer recurrence, where $|\beta|<1$).

Just to be sure this is not trivial, there numbers without this property, such as $\sqrt k$ for any nonsquare integer $k$.

**Is there a name for this property?** Or a general theory of such numbers? Are there nontrivial ones that are not quadratic over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: A quick extension of your result so far: if $m,n,q$ (positive integers) are chosen such that $|m - \sqrt{n}| < q < m + \sqrt{n}$, then 
$$
\frac{m + \sqrt{n}}{q}
$$
Will be such a number.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Sorry, calculator error. But $\frac{5+\sqrt{11}}2$ appears to be a counterexample.

Comment: That would be related to the recurrence
$$
a_n = 5 a_{n-1} + \frac 72 a_n
$$
I think that fractional coefficient is what throws this off.  We can add a condition, then

Comment: It seems that we must additionally have $q^2 \mid (m^2 - n)$

Comment: @OlivierOloa: No, I didn't know that. I did think that my method here should generalize to such numbers (without knowing they had a name) but couldn't complete the argument when the degree was higher than 2. Thanks.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are welcome.

Comment: What about $(m+\frac 1M)^n$ with $M$ very big?

Comment: @OlivierOloa not sure why you deleted your comment; it's probably interesting to most people looking at this problem.  For the reference of others: this question seems related to the idea of [Pisot numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Do you have a concrete example with $q>2$? With your added condition I think we do get a recurrence with integer coefficients, but we _also_ need to have particular base values that are integers, such that the coefficient of $\alpha^n$ in the solution becomes $1$.

Comment: Interestingly, $\frac{5 + \sqrt{16}}{3}$ fits this requirement

Comment: $\frac{5 + \sqrt{34}}{3}$ seems more along the lines of what we're looking for, though

Comment: Or, we could simply take $\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + q^2}}{q}$ for any $q$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Experimentally the fractional parts of $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{10}}3\right)^n$ (for $q=3$) in your latest formula do not appear to converge, though ....

Comment: Well... how many steps does it take for $[(1 - \sqrt{10})/3]^n$ to become "small"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: That happens fairly quickly. The problem, however, is that $$ \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{10}}3\right)^n + \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{10}}3\right)^n$$ is not an integer for $n=1$, so we don't get an integer sequence started even if the _recurrence_ has integer coefficients.

Comment: All right, I gave it a shot.  Interesting question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

they are called Pisot numbers, after a 1938 thesis, though Thue in 1912 and Hardy in 1919 also noticed them. Pisot characterized them in a rather beautiful theorem.
here's a wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number

Comment: Those are related, but not quite the same

Comment: They are at least a subset of the numbers I'm talking about, so +1 -- but as far as the Wikipedia article seems to say, it may be possible for the fractional parts of $\alpha^n$ converge to $0$ _slower than_ square-summable, yet the number is not Pisot.

Comment: The coefficient $\lambda$ in the definition seems to complicate things as well

Comment: when i looked into this a while ago i assumed that was an open question. i think Pisot's results show such numbers, if any exist, must be transcendental, but my memory is not clear on this point. i'd like to study Pisot's proof of his main theorem, but i'm waiting till i have a bit more maturity in analysis

Comment: Hm, yes I see further down in the article it does say that Pisot numbers are the only _algebraic_ reals $>1$ with this propterty, and that the existence of transcendental examples is open. I think that settles it.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom btw sorry i didn't see you had already referenced Pisot, due to delayed comment feed. my first hint was when i noticed this property in integer powers of the golden section on a pocket calculator.